# Error when trying to post to rest endpoint. Spring Boot/JPA

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa

Im having trouble trying to post data to the rest endpoint. Here is he relevant code.

FROM C-URL

```
curl -d '{"description":"description", "image":[80,5,78], "name":"Peter"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/abouts
```

-
this is the error i get in the C-URL response

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-20T07:45:18.961+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into about (id, description, image, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement","path":"/abouts"}
```

--schema.sql

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
create table about (id bigint not null, description varchar(255), image binary(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table article (id bigint not null, description varchar(255), image binary(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table menu_item (id bigint not null, description varchar(255), image binary(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

--Entity Class

```
@Data
public class About {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@NotEmpty
private String name;
@NotEmpty
private String description;
private byte[] image;
}
```

--RestController

```
package coffee.controller;

import coffee.*;
import coffee.data.AboutRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;



@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="abouts",
                produces="application/json",
                consumes="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class AboutController {

    private AboutRepository aboutRepo;

    public AboutController(AboutRepository aboutRepo) {
        this.aboutRepo = aboutRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<About> getAbouts() {
        return aboutRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{aboutId}")
    public ResponseEntity<About> aboutById(@PathVariable("aboutId") Long id) {
        Optional<About> optAbout = aboutRepo.findById(id);
        if (optAbout.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(optAbout.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public About postAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
        return aboutRepo.save(about);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{aboutId}")
    public About putAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
        return aboutRepo.save(about);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{aboutId")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteEvent (@PathVariable("aboutId") Long aboutId) {
        try {
            aboutRepo.deleteById(aboutId);
        }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

--AboutRepo just uses Spring generated repository

```
package coffee.data;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import coffee.*;

public interface AboutRepository extends CrudRepository<About, Long> {
```

### }

error  in STS console when performing post in C-URL

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSequence(Parser.java:5970) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3131) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCall(Parser.java:4854) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:382) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:304) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at coffee.controller.AboutController.postAbout(AboutController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

When I change @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY), it still shows an error message both in C-URL and the STS console but a different one. 
CURL

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-20T08:01:15.230+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into about (id, description, image, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement","path":"/abouts"}
```

STS Console

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ABOUT" not found; SQL statement:
insert into about (id, description, image, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5920) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5897) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1220) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:431) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1166) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:325) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2933) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3524) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:637) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

Comment: share your complete error stack trace.

Comment: my program starts up fine with no error but ill post stack trace

Comment: Can you attach aboutRepo.save method ? I think JSON is correct. It is somewhere failing in inserting the object. A rest call with faulty JSON should fail even before calling aboutRepo.save.

Comment: added, the repo is just using a spring data generated repository

Comment: ok thanks. In debug do you see the About object created properly in postAbout method ?

Comment: Need to remove final keyword from About class private members and generate getter/setter for the same.

Comment: i did that and now i get a new error message when trying to make a post in c-url. please see edit.

Comment: the c-url response is still the same above, the new error is in the sts console

Comment: So you haven't created this "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" ... not that this has the slightest thing to do with JSON,

Comment: Yeah in the beginning I thought it was my JSON but it turned out to be my entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the final keyword from data members of class About and generate Getters and Setters instead. Something like this:

**About.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
public class About {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    private byte[] image;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**AboutRepository.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AboutRepository extends CrudRepository<About, Long>{

}
```

To see the complete code, please refer to: https://github.com/kunalpurimkbk/stackoverflow_53385609/

Comment: i think my question wasn't clear, sorry. Im trying to use c-url to post data into the rest endpoint using JSON. However, im not sure exactly how my JSON syntax is supposed to look for my entity

Comment: I tried sending the JSON that you mentioned in the question before the edit. It worked fine. I also don't think that there is any issue with JSON.

Comment: changed entity class and received new error updated above when sending the post method in c-url

Comment: the c-url response is still the same above, the new error is in the sts console

Comment: @Peter I am sending payload `{"description":"description", "image":[80,5,78], "name":"Peter"}` using Postman and it just works fine. Even `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` works for me.

Comment: I was using the updated entity class but was still getting the error. The reason why was because I had some schema-generation properties. Once i got rid of those it worked. Thank you
Actually i reverted to my final properties and it still works. I guess it was the schema-generation properties the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

As Kunal has said, you need to remove final keywords from About class members and to add getters and setters.

The thing that is still missing is to add appropriate sequence generator for id.
By default hibernate_sequence table is required to hold a sequence for id.
To make things work you need to add:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```